# Links in Reference List. DOI vs URL in `elsarticle-num.bst`

Tags: bst

**A picture for context**

[image]

---

**A few observations**

When `doi` field is defined in the `.bib` file, the bibliography style appends it very nicely at the end of the reference, as it can be seen in [3]. In addition, we can see that the `title` of the reference is also a link, but that is only because there is additional `url` field defined. This field is also printed at the end of the reference, as also shown in [3].

In [4], the `url` is omitted. Instead the `eprint` field is given, containing the arxiveId, which nicely puts a link at the end. In the same way it happens to the `doi` field, here the `arxivId` also does not turns the `title` into a link.

---

I don't like the way things are. Assuming its ok to do minor changes to the provided Elsevier template, how to print the title as a link when either `doi`, `arxiv` or `URL` are provided?

Comment: I would assume it is *not* ok to do any changes to their template. I would rather remove the `doi` and `eprint` fields, and provide `url` fields on all entries.